# How can I generate a report for the financial transaction entered by USERS of certain "drupal Role"?

Tags: civireport, roles

Finance department wants a weekly report of contributions taken by our shop. I have set up a drupal user role called "Shop" and permissions accordingly, and added staff to that role. But cant figure out how can I generate the report for the contribution specifically created  by those staffs of “SHOP”. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "contribution specifically made by those users" - which 'users'? those with the Role = Shop? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Thx. It didn't make sense to me that it would be the staff of shop who do the purchases, but i guess you have it set up so the purchase is made in their name rather than the customer. You could also use a unique Contribution Type called 'shop purchases' perhaps, so it isn't actually about 'who' buys it but 'what gets bought'?

Comment: I think my question still not clear enough. Sorry! What I want is, a list of Contribution details (mostly cash donation handed in person by donor) inputted into CiviCRM by a group of backoffice user to spot any discrepancies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When someone adds a Contribution via the backend (eg Add Contribution) then an Activity is created (Type = Contribution) which will record who added that Contribution.

If you use that fact, and set up your 'users' in a Group either manually or smart group per Aidan's answer, then you might be able to build an Activity based report to show the contributions they added.

Comment: Yes. I think that’s what I needed. I have already included users in a group. Thanks for the hint

Comment: Great, can you accept the answer?

Comment: Is there a chance I could include "Payment method" option appear in one of the column in the report? thanks

Comment: I also would like to see the donor name in the report. it seems only in certain conditions donor name (target name) appears in report. is there a way to achieve this please? thanks

Comment: have a look at the actual Activities, do they all have 'target name'. if so it does seem odd if the Report then misses some out.

Comment: other option would be to look at doing this in drupal views. not sure about the Payment method. Since it is not part of the Activity then I don't think you can get that via this route.

Answer (score 2):

You could sync your Drupal role to a Civi group with the [CiviGroup Roles Sync module](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/#civigroup-roles-sync) then use the group in the report filter criteria.

Comment: How do I install this module?

Comment: It's installed with the normal CiviCRM Drupal package of files so just go to your Drupal modules page and enabled it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sql skills you may be better with an sql query of the log_civicrm_contribution table with left joins 'Group' so you can filter to the 'Shop' people, and just look for the 'insert' value in the log table. Then you may be able to join in the other values you are saying you need in